# Why does this xml query in SQL Server not work

Tags: sql-server, xml

Lately I was blown by xml for SQL Server, but this one here gets me nuts

```
DECLARE @xml XML;
SET @xml = '
    <ROOT>
        <Object>
            <FooProperty1>123</FooProperty1>
            <FooProperty2>456</FooProperty2>
        </Object>
        <Object>
            <FooProperty1>123</FooProperty1>
            <FooProperty2>456</FooProperty2>
        </Object>
    </ROOT>
';

SELECT  [doc].[FooProperty1].value('.', 'INT') AS [fooProperty1],
        [doc].[FooProperty2].value('.', 'INT') AS [fooProperty2]
FROM    @xml.nodes('/ROOT/Object')
AS      [doc]
(
    [FooProperty1],
    [FooProperty2]
)
```

Gives me

> Msg 8159, Level 16, State 1, Line 22
>   'doc' has fewer columns than were
>   specified in the column list.

Does msg does not change if I change change `@xml` as

```
SET @xml = '
    <ROOT>
        <Object FooProperty1="123" FooProperty2="456"/>
        <Object FooProperty1="123" FooProperty2="456"/>
    </ROOT>
';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your XQuery is not correct, I believe - try this instead:

```
SELECT  
    Root.Obj.value('(FooProperty1)[1]', 'INT') AS [fooProperty1],
    Root.Obj.value('(FooProperty2)[1]', 'INT') AS [fooProperty2]
FROM
    @xml.nodes('/ROOT/Object') AS Root(Obj)
```

The `@xml.nodes()` defines XML fragments - one for each entry in the XPath - and you need to assign it a two-identifier alias for a pseudo-table with a single column (format: `Root(Obj)`). That single column of that pseudo-table is the XML fragment your XPath query selected from the XML document.

Based on that alias, you can then reach into those XML fragments and pull out the various properties.

**Update:** for your second XML, with the XML attributes, use this instead:

```
SELECT  
    Root.Obj.value('(@FooProperty1)[1]', 'INT') AS [fooProperty1],
    Root.Obj.value('(@FooProperty2)[1]', 'INT') AS [fooProperty2]
FROM
    @xml.nodes('/ROOT/Object') AS Root(Obj)
```

By specifying `@FooProperty1` you're grabbing the XML **attribute** instead of the XML sub-element from that `<ROOT>/<Object>` node you're currently looking at.

Comment: This approach does only work, if I am using the first pattern with extra elements for each column ... Could you maybe give me an example for the second pattern?

Comment: @Andreas Niedermair: updated my response to also handle your second scenario (with XML attributes)